# Language changing to default English when the application in split screen mode

Tags: android, split-screen

In my application,I have given three languages option for the user. When user select the language the view is changing to that language mode.But when user trying to split the screen the language is resetting to default English mode.How can I handle this?

Comment: i also have same problem. Did u found any fix??